# How to configure Apache Tobago

Tags: jsf, myfaces, tobago

I am experimenting with Apache Tobago v6.0 (and Apache MyFaces).

On using Tobago, I am told it cannot initialise without a tobago-config.xml.  I see an example or two and the relevant xsd, but I cannot find any documentation or explanation of the tags such as <ordering> or <create-session-secret> and so on.

Where can I find the relevant documentation to allow me to configure Tobago correctly for my app?